# how to connect parent-xml and child-xml in spring

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, reference

I want to know how to connect(reference) parent-xml and child-xml in spring.

I have two xml which one is context.xml(parent-xml) and the other is contextSub.xml(child-xml).
Also, I have one test class.

What I want is that without writing setup() method, how to connect(or reference) two xml(parent-xml and child-xml)?

In setup() method, there are some logic(cording) to make context.xml child-xml connect(to connect context.xml and child-xml). But I think there is another way to connect them. 
Alredy, I tried that I wrote

```
import resource="classpath:/test/src/main/resources/context.xml"
```

in contextSub.xml, but it didn't work. 
Could you please let me know?
Is there any wrong cording?

*******context.xml *******

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

```
<bean id="hello" class="com.nana.service.Hello">
    <property name="name" >
        <value>HongSangJik</value>
    </property>
    <property name="printer" ref="consolePrint" />
</bean>

<bean id="consolePrint" class="com.nana.service.ConsolePrinter" />
```

****** contextSub.xml ******

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

```
<bean id="helloSub" class="com.nana.service.Hello">
    <property name="name">
        <value>HongGilDong</value>
    </property>
    <property name="printer" ref="consolePrint" />
</bean>
```

******** HelloTest.java ********

```
 package com.nana.service;

    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(locations="/context.xml")

    public class HelloTest {
    ApplicationContext context;
    ApplicationContext subContext;
    Hello hello;
    Hello hellosub;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        context= 
                new GenericXmlApplicationContext("/context.xml");
        hello = context.getBean("hello", Hello.class);
        GenericApplicationContext child= 
                new GenericApplicationContext(context);
        XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(child);
        reader.loadBeanDefinitions("contextSub.xml");
        child.refresh();
        hellosub=child.getBean("helloSub", Hello.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void sayHelloTest() {
        assertThat("Hello!HongSangJik", is(hello.sayHello()));
        assertThat("Hello!HongGilDong", is(hellosub.sayHello()));

    }
}
```

---------------After updating setup() code
***[HelloTest]***

```
package com.nana.service;
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations="/context.xml")


public class HelloTest {
ApplicationContext context;
ApplicationContext subContext;
Hello hello;
Hello hellosub;

@Before
public void setup() {

    context= new GenericXmlApplicationContext("/context.xml");
    hello = context.getBean("hello", Hello.class);
    hellosub=context.getBean("helloSub", Hello.class);

}

@Test
public void sayHelloTest() {
    assertThat("Hello!HongSangJik", is(hello.sayHello()));
    assertThat("Hello!HongGilDong", is(hellosub.sayHello()));

}
```

}

****[context.xml]****

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

```
<bean id="helloSub" class="com.nana.service.Hello">
    <property name="name">
        <value>HongGilDong</value>
    </property>
    <property name="printer" ref="consolePrint" />
</bean>
```

Comment: contextSub.xml need consolePrint which is located in context.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your context.xml is parent-xml and contextSub.xml is child-xml, I would try adding this line to context.xml:

```
<import resource="contextSub.xml"/>
```

and remove the `<import....>` from contextSub.xml file.

In the java code we only need to load "context.xml" file.

```
@Before
public void setup()
{
    context= new GenericXmlApplicationContext("/context.xml");
    hello = context.getBean("hello", Hello.class);
    hellosub=context.getBean("helloSub", Hello.class);
}
```

Comment: I tried, but NullPointException appeared at assertThat("Hello!HongSangJik", is(hello.sayHello())); .

Comment: Can you post the Failure Trace of the NullPointerException?
I tried creating a test project by putting together all your code and it runs successfully. (See my updated answer with setup() code)

Comment: Sure! After updating your setup() code, NoSuchBeanDefinitionExceptionError appeared.

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'hellosub' available
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1207)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
 at

Comment: This is the first time using this web site, therefore I am sorry that  I don't know how I can post error code.

Comment: Oh, gosh! I success!!! Thank you so much! Because I put "/" in import resource code. Thank you sooo much! I hope have you a wonderful day! If you hope I should do sth(select your answer etc), please add comment.